# Find the list element, in a list of classes, that has the minimum attribute `X`

Tags: r, list, class, min

How can I possibly identify which is the element in a list of classes, that has the min attribute X, among the others attributes X in the list?

Let me show you what I mean, in a more concrete way.

```
# class setup
setClass(
   "Stackoverflow",
   slots = list(
     x = "numeric",
     y = "numeric"
  )
)

#generate the list of classes
l = list()
for (i in 1:10)
{
  l[[i]] <- myLove4U <- new("Stackoverflow", 
                             x = runif(1, min=0, max=100), 
                             t = runif(1, min=0, max=100)  
                            )  
}

#find which is the element that has the smallest x
# ??
```

The question mark take place the code that I wish to know how to implement.
I have tried, with no good results what so ever, this way:  `min(l[]@x)`

This would make me know which is the minimum value, among them all, and then search for the index that has it.

Because I could not even find the minimum value, I'm completely lost. Could you please help me find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a way of solving it, with not that much computational cost is by executing for

```
c = c()
for (i in 1:length(l))
{
    c[i] = l[[i]]@x
}

pos = which(c == min(c))
```